Docker build of python application can't find installed module
First:  I'm a beginner at Docker.
I'm trying to dockerise a python application that uses numerous (~12 GiB) of modules.  The application is persnickety about which version of modules it uses.
The application is: https://github.com/rakuri255/UltraSinger
It seems to dockerise fine, but when it runs, the python program is unable to find the Levenshtein module:
# docker run ultra-singer --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/USinger/UltraSinger.py", line 8, in <module>
    import Levenshtein
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein'

Why can't it find this module?
The docker log shows it as being installed:
...
#12 144.4 Downloading python_Levenshtein-0.25.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
...
#12 534.2 Installing collected packages: tensorboard-plugin-wit, [snip], requests-oauthlib, python-levenshtein, pylint, [snip], whisperx

EDIT:
As per @Ramhound's suggestion, the output of pip show python-levenshtein:
#13 [9/9] RUN pip show python-levenshtein
#13 0.972 Name: python-Levenshtein
#13 0.972 Version: 0.25.1
#13 0.972 Summary: Python extension for computing string edit distances and similarities.
#13 0.972 Home-page: https://github.com/rapidfuzz/python-Levenshtein
#13 0.972 Author: Max Bachmann
#13 0.972 Author-email: pypi@maxbachmann.de
#13 0.972 License: GPL-2.0-or-later
#13 0.973 Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
#13 0.973 Requires: Levenshtein
#13 0.973 Required-by: 
#13 DONE 1.0s

EDIT2:
After trying unsuccessfully to adjust the python import path in the Dockerfile, I just put it in the .py:
sys.path.append( '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' )   # for Levenshtein
print( "### sys.path IS " + str( sys.path ) )

Interestingly, the path includes Python 3.11 components, when the Dockerfile specifies Python 3.10
### sys.path IS ['/opt/USinger', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

And the problem persists, albeit in a modified form:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/USinger/UltraSinger.py", line 12, in <module>
    import Levenshtein
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Levenshtein/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from Levenshtein.levenshtein_cpp import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein.levenshtein_cpp'

EDIT3:
I retried using RUN pip3.10 install --upgrade certifi -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt, but still saw the python path referencing 3.11
I created a simple Dockerfile myself:
FROM python:3.10
COPY src /opt/USinger/
COPY assets /opt/USinger/
COPY requirements.txt /opt/USinger/
WORKDIR /opt/USinger/
RUN pip3.10 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3.10 install levenshtein==0.25.1
RUN pip3.10 install --upgrade certifi -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt
#RUN pip show python-levenshtein
#ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages"
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/USinger/UltraSinger.py"]

Note that this used to use pip install ... but I changed to pip3 in desperation; the exact problem remains.
I also added a "shebang" to UltraSinger.py.
Is there any way to debug this?
Full Docker Log:
~/Software/UltraSinger
[snugglepot] docker build -t ultra-singer --no-cache --progress=plain  .
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 389B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10
#2 DONE 0.9s

#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10@sha256:08a49662edbfff8a296e2db2cb3235e117d1caeb09c32cba65011a2de0306440
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 2.63kB done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [2/8] COPY src /opt/USinger/
#6 DONE 0.1s

#7 [3/8] COPY assets /opt/USinger/
#7 DONE 0.1s

#8 [4/8] COPY requirements.txt /opt/USinger/
#8 DONE 0.1s

#9 [5/8] WORKDIR /opt/USinger/
#9 DONE 0.1s

#10 [6/8] RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
#10 2.003 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.0.1)
#10 2.289 Collecting pip
#10 2.497   Downloading pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
#10 3.186      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 3.281 Installing collected packages: pip
#10 3.281   Attempting uninstall: pip
#10 3.282     Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
#10 3.490     Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
#10 3.681       Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
#10 4.719 Successfully installed pip-24.2
#10 4.719 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
#10 DONE 5.1s

#11 [7/8] RUN pip3 install levenshtein==0.25.1
#11 1.477 Collecting levenshtein==0.25.1
#11 1.651   Downloading Levenshtein-0.25.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
#11 2.832 Collecting rapidfuzz<4.0.0,>=3.8.0 (from levenshtein==0.25.1)
#11 2.882   Downloading rapidfuzz-3.10.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
#11 2.962 Downloading Levenshtein-0.25.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (177 kB)
#11 3.111 Downloading rapidfuzz-3.10.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
#11 3.680    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 5.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#11 3.717 Installing collected packages: rapidfuzz, levenshtein
#11 3.897 Successfully installed levenshtein-0.25.1 rapidfuzz-3.10.0
#11 3.897 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager, possibly rendering your system unusable.It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv. Use the --root-user-action option if you know what you are doing and want to suppress this warning.
#11 DONE 4.3s

#12 [8/8] RUN pip3 install --upgrade certifi -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt
#12 0.988 Collecting whisperx@ git+https://github.com/m-bain/whisperx.git (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 654))
#12 0.989   Cloning https://github.com/m-bain/whisperx.git to /tmp/pip-install-k7a311po/whisperx_181e6df6599445028d1732f0eb911f48
#12 0.990   Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/m-bain/whisperx.git /tmp/pip-install-k7a311po/whisperx_181e6df6599445028d1732f0eb911f48
#12 3.277   Resolved https://github.com/m-bain/whisperx.git to commit 9e3a9e0e38fcec1304e1784381059a0e2c670be5
#12 3.279   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#12 3.942   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 4.200 Collecting certifi
#12 4.393   Downloading certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
#12 4.481 Collecting absl-py==2.1.0 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 7))
#12 4.536   Downloading absl_py-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
#12 5.231 Collecting aiohttp==3.9.5 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 11))
#12 5.264   Downloading aiohttp-3.9.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (7.5 kB)
#12 5.365 Collecting aiosignal==1.3.1 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 13))
#12 5.415   Downloading aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
#12 5.543 Collecting alembic==1.13.2 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 15))
#12 5.587   Downloading alembic-1.13.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
#12 5.666 Collecting antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 17))
#12 5.716   Downloading antlr4-python3-runtime-4.9.3.tar.gz (117 kB)
#12 5.846   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#12 6.110   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 6.163 Collecting appdirs==1.4.4 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 19))
#12 6.206   Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
#12 6.290 Collecting asteroid-filterbanks==0.4.0 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 21))
#12 6.345   Downloading asteroid_filterbanks-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
#12 6.503 Collecting astroid==3.2.4 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 23))
#12 6.545   Downloading astroid-3.2.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
#12 6.623 Collecting astunparse==1.6.3 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 25))
#12 6.656   Downloading astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
#12 6.734 Collecting async-timeout==4.0.3 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 27))
#12 6.786   Downloading async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
#12 6.876 Collecting attrs==23.2.0 (from -r /opt/USinger/requirements.txt (line 29))

[snip] to maintain post-size limit

#12 292.2 Downloading yarl-1.9.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (301 kB)
#12 292.3 Downloading yt_dlp-2024.7.25-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
#12 292.6    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 292.7 Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410.6 MB)
#12 332.7    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 410.6/410.6 MB 10.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 332.8 Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.1 MB)
#12 334.4    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.1/14.1 MB 8.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 334.4 Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (23.7 MB)
#12 336.8    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.7/23.7 MB 10.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 336.8 Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (823 kB)
#12 336.9    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 823.6/823.6 kB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 336.9 Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-9.1.0.70-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (664.8 MB)
#12 401.2    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 664.8/664.8 MB 10.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 401.2 Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.2.54-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (121.6 MB)
#12 412.4    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 121.6/121.6 MB 10.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 412.4 Downloading nvidia_curand_cu12-10.3.2.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (56.5 MB)
#12 417.9    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 56.5/56.5 MB 10.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 417.9 Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu12-11.4.5.107-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (124.2 MB)
#12 429.8    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 124.2/124.2 MB 10.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 429.8 Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu12-12.1.0.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (196.0 MB)
#12 449.0    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 196.0/196.0 MB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 449.1 Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu12-2.20.5-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (176.2 MB)
#12 466.4    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 176.2/176.2 MB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 466.4 Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (99 kB)
#12 466.5 Downloading triton-3.0.0-1-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl (209.4 MB)
#12 487.2    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 209.4/209.4 MB 10.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 487.2 Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
#12 487.2 Downloading nvidia_nvjitlink_cu12-12.6.68-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (19.7 MB)
#12 489.3    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.7/19.7 MB 9.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#12 504.0 Building wheels for collected packages: antlr4-python3-runtime, crepe, demucs, docopt, dora-search, julius, pretty-midi, resampy, treetable, whisperx
#12 504.0   Building wheel for antlr4-python3-runtime (setup.py): started
#12 504.6   Building wheel for antlr4-python3-runtime (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 504.6   Created wheel for antlr4-python3-runtime: filename=antlr4_python3_runtime-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl size=144556 sha256=36ca0317456772c129dbb6c87ec5538708f927269d5db44f50a4a34fd214b043
#12 504.6   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/12/93/dd/1f6a127edc45659556564c5730f6d4e300888f4bca2d4c5a88
#12 504.6   Building wheel for crepe (setup.py): started
#12 528.4   Building wheel for crepe (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 528.9   Created wheel for crepe: filename=crepe-0.0.15-py3-none-any.whl size=134848687 sha256=6200b58ac91043f572dcfcfa32ab9f076958afaf4db761a052398194041eabb8
#12 528.9   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/48/0d/5a/0303421c941420cffb0eb8f35bddd5da10e5eef3813118a9ef
#12 528.9   Building wheel for demucs (setup.py): started
#12 529.5   Building wheel for demucs (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 529.5   Created wheel for demucs: filename=demucs-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=78388 sha256=137fa55bbe8ea2e084ec8d9e66bb941b49cc5d2f39db55d02403b8ed6b4bddb1
#12 529.5   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/2a/65/a1/6cc0e525a84375af3b09823b3326b0ece53c4e68302c054548
#12 529.5   Building wheel for docopt (setup.py): started
#12 529.9   Building wheel for docopt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 529.9   Created wheel for docopt: filename=docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=13706 sha256=41b0b7f60029e833a062568adde5d6d17750fda102d9c73eb993293a54b574e0
#12 529.9   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/fc/ab/d4/5da2067ac95b36618c629a5f93f809425700506f72c9732fac
#12 529.9   Building wheel for dora-search (pyproject.toml): started
#12 530.3   Building wheel for dora-search (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#12 530.3   Created wheel for dora-search: filename=dora_search-0.1.12-py3-none-any.whl size=75092 sha256=6395a7e6764e684b132cd4420316afbc27970e6d7012f9a11f76743f6c309cf5
#12 530.3   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b1/c2/c0/bea5cc405497284d584b958f293ef32c23bad42ae5e44d973c
#12 530.3   Building wheel for julius (setup.py): started
#12 530.7   Building wheel for julius (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 530.7   Created wheel for julius: filename=julius-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl size=21870 sha256=2f3d71f2a1f406d4345e12f6e3884441bf0e4dd6b95c6054c72d95f37460f3e5
#12 530.7   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b9/b2/05/f883527ffcb7f2ead5438a2c23439aa0c881eaa9a4c80256f4
#12 530.7   Building wheel for pretty-midi (setup.py): started
#12 531.5   Building wheel for pretty-midi (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 531.5   Created wheel for pretty-midi: filename=pretty_midi-0.2.10-py3-none-any.whl size=5592285 sha256=72537b613def6b2259c4223dd06677c6ea842360dd2be58bf00d43bef2da7031
#12 531.5   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/cd/a5/30/7b8b7f58709f5150f67f98fde4b891ebf0be9ef07a8af49f25
#12 531.5   Building wheel for resampy (setup.py): started
#12 531.9   Building wheel for resampy (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 531.9   Created wheel for resampy: filename=resampy-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl size=320704 sha256=e64fdfe34c55831363321151da796c75b8c4ef1f7670817f20f9fca94ba35590
#12 531.9   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/a0/79/29e61754e5b3941ad4c7d01bf5bea99768e64e4bdd3180f32b
#12 531.9   Building wheel for treetable (setup.py): started
#12 532.2   Building wheel for treetable (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 532.2   Created wheel for treetable: filename=treetable-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl size=7331 sha256=8324519aee5a196f533d97b149ebc712f4e2a1726b52cd7d6d4de36d1f843f96
#12 532.2   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/72/55/0e/91c3655bdb162446f8a7cd477579397544454a63ae7c599c0c
#12 532.2   Building wheel for whisperx (setup.py): started
#12 532.6   Building wheel for whisperx (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#12 532.6   Created wheel for whisperx: filename=whisperx-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=38486 sha256=8cb47c07f2956510829dfa885718cd5fff3ca1896a0c46c57f5e5d69238db647
#12 532.6   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-6bz9bwfv/wheels/27/fb/53/682b85073a466f1866910d7257233e53b0cc126ab50e7c5373
#12 532.6 Successfully built antlr4-python3-runtime crepe demucs docopt dora-search julius pretty-midi resampy treetable whisperx
#12 534.2 Installing collected packages: tensorboard-plugin-wit, sortedcontainers, sentencepiece, pytz, pyreadline3, pydub, primepy, mpmath, libclang, lameenc, keras, flatbuffers, docopt, dataclasses, brotli, appdirs, antlr4-python3-runtime, wrapt, wheel, websockets, webcolors, urllib3, unidecode, tzdata, typing-extensions, treetable, tqdm, tomlkit, tomli, threadpoolctl, termcolor, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard-data-server, tabulate, sympy, six, shellingham, setuptools, semver, safetensors, ruamel-yaml-clib, regex, rapidfuzz, pyyaml, pyparsing, pygments, pycryptodomex, pycparser, pyasn1, protobuf, pluggy, platformdirs, pillow, pathspec, packaging, oauthlib, nvidia-nvtx-cu12, nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12, nvidia-nccl-cu12, nvidia-curand-cu12, nvidia-cufft-cu12, nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12, nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12, nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12, nvidia-cublas-cu12, numpy, networkx, mypy-extensions, mutagen, musicbrainzngs, multidict, more-itertools, mdurl, mccabe, markupsafe, markdown, llvmlite, kiwisolver, jsonpickle, joblib, isort, iniconfig, idna, humanfriendly, grpcio, greenlet, gast, future, fsspec, frozenlist, fonttools, filelock, exceptiongroup, einops, dill, decorator, cycler, colorlog, colorama, cloudpickle, click, charset-normalizer, chardet, certifi, cachetools, av, audioread, attrs, async-timeout, absl-py, yarl, werkzeug, typing-inspect, triton, tensorboardx, submitit, sqlalchemy, scipy, ruamel-yaml, rsa, retrying, requests, python-dateutil, pytest, pyasn1-modules, opt-einsum, omegaconf, nvidia-cusparse-cu12, nvidia-cudnn-cu12, numba, nltk, mido, marshmallow, markdown-it-py, marisa-trie, mako, lightning-utilities, keras-preprocessing, jinja2, imageio, h5py, google-pasta, ffmpeg-python, ctranslate2, contourpy, coloredlogs, cffi, black, astunparse, astroid, aiosignal, yt-dlp, soundfile, scikit-learn, rich, resampy, requests-oauthlib, python-levenshtein, pylint, pyhyphen-reloaded, pyannote-core, pretty-midi, pooch, pandas, onnxruntime, nvidia-cusolver-cu12, matplotlib, language-data, hyperpyyaml, huggingface-hub, google-auth, dataclasses-json, alembic, aiohttp, typer, torch, tokenizers, optuna, music21, librosa, langcodes, hmmlearn, google-auth-oauthlib, transformers, torchmetrics, torchaudio, tensorboard, pytorch-metric-learning, pyannote-database, julius, faster-whisper, dora-search, crepe, asteroid-filterbanks, torch-pitch-shift, tensorflow, speechbrain, pytorch-lightning, pyannote-pipeline, pyannote-metrics, openunmix, torch-audiomentations, lightning, demucs, pyannote-audio, whisperx
#12 537.2   Attempting uninstall: wheel
#12 537.2     Found existing installation: wheel 0.44.0
#12 537.2     Uninstalling wheel-0.44.0:
#12 537.2       Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.44.0
#12 545.6   Attempting uninstall: setuptools
#12 545.6     Found existing installation: setuptools 65.5.1
#12 545.6     Uninstalling setuptools-65.5.1:
#12 545.8       Successfully uninstalled setuptools-65.5.1
#12 547.1   Attempting uninstall: rapidfuzz
#12 547.1     Found existing installation: RapidFuzz 3.10.0
#12 547.1     Uninstalling RapidFuzz-3.10.0:
#12 547.1       Successfully uninstalled RapidFuzz-3.10.0
#12 670.3 Successfully installed absl-py-2.1.0 aiohttp-3.9.5 aiosignal-1.3.1 alembic-1.13.2 antlr4-python3-runtime-4.9.3 appdirs-1.4.4 asteroid-filterbanks-0.4.0 astroid-3.2.4 astunparse-1.6.3 async-timeout-4.0.3 attrs-23.2.0 audioread-3.0.1 av-11.0.0 black-24.4.2 brotli-1.1.0 cachetools-5.4.0 certifi-2024.7.4 cffi-1.16.0 chardet-5.2.0 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 click-8.1.7 cloudpickle-3.0.0 colorama-0.4.6 coloredlogs-15.0.1 colorlog-6.8.2 contourpy-1.2.1 crepe-0.0.15 ctranslate2-4.3.1 cycler-0.12.1 dataclasses-0.6 dataclasses-json-0.6.7 decorator-5.1.1 demucs-4.0.1 dill-0.3.8 docopt-0.6.2 dora-search-0.1.12 einops-0.8.0 exceptiongroup-1.2.2 faster-whisper-1.0.0 ffmpeg-python-0.2.0 filelock-3.15.4 flatbuffers-24.3.25 fonttools-4.53.1 frozenlist-1.4.1 fsspec-2024.6.1 future-1.0.0 gast-0.4.0 google-auth-2.32.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 google-pasta-0.2.0 greenlet-3.0.3 grpcio-1.65.1 h5py-3.11.0 hmmlearn-0.3.2 huggingface-hub-0.24.2 humanfriendly-10.0 hyperpyyaml-1.2.2 idna-3.7 imageio-2.34.2 iniconfig-2.0.0 isort-5.13.2 jinja2-3.1.4 joblib-1.4.2 jsonpickle-3.2.2 julius-0.2.7 keras-2.10.0 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 kiwisolver-1.4.5 lameenc-1.7.0 langcodes-3.4.0 language-data-1.2.0 libclang-18.1.1 librosa-0.9.2 lightning-2.3.3 lightning-utilities-0.11.6 llvmlite-0.43.0 mako-1.3.5 marisa-trie-1.2.0 markdown-3.6 markdown-it-py-3.0.0 markupsafe-2.1.5 marshmallow-3.21.3 matplotlib-3.9.1 mccabe-0.7.0 mdurl-0.1.2 mido-1.3.2 more-itertools-10.3.0 mpmath-1.3.0 multidict-6.0.5 music21-9.1.0 musicbrainzngs-0.7.1 mutagen-1.47.0 mypy-extensions-1.0.0 networkx-3.3 nltk-3.8.1 numba-0.60.0 numpy-1.26.4 nvidia-cublas-cu12-12.1.3.1 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12-12.1.105 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12-12.1.105 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12-12.1.105 nvidia-cudnn-cu12-9.1.0.70 nvidia-cufft-cu12-11.0.2.54 nvidia-curand-cu12-10.3.2.106 nvidia-cusolver-cu12-11.4.5.107 nvidia-cusparse-cu12-12.1.0.106 nvidia-nccl-cu12-2.20.5 nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12-12.6.68 nvidia-nvtx-cu12-12.1.105 oauthlib-3.2.2 omegaconf-2.3.0 onnxruntime-1.18.1 openunmix-1.3.0 opt-einsum-3.3.0 optuna-3.6.1 packaging-23.2 pandas-2.2.2 pathspec-0.12.1 pillow-10.4.0 platformdirs-4.2.2 pluggy-1.5.0 pooch-1.8.2 pretty-midi-0.2.10 primepy-1.3 protobuf-3.19.6 pyannote-audio-3.1.1 pyannote-core-5.0.0 pyannote-database-5.1.0 pyannote-metrics-3.2.1 pyannote-pipeline-3.0.1 pyasn1-0.6.0 pyasn1-modules-0.4.0 pycparser-2.22 pycryptodomex-3.20.0 pydub-0.25.1 pygments-2.18.0 pyhyphen-reloaded-4.0.6 pylint-3.2.6 pyparsing-3.1.2 pyreadline3-3.4.1 pytest-8.3.2 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 python-levenshtein-0.25.1 pytorch-lightning-2.3.3 pytorch-metric-learning-2.6.0 pytz-2024.1 pyyaml-6.0.1 rapidfuzz-3.9.4 regex-2024.7.24 requests-2.32.3 requests-oauthlib-2.0.0 resampy-0.2.2 retrying-1.3.4 rich-13.7.1 rsa-4.9 ruamel-yaml-0.18.6 ruamel-yaml-clib-0.2.8 safetensors-0.4.3 scikit-learn-1.5.1 scipy-1.14.0 semver-3.0.2 sentencepiece-0.2.0 setuptools-75.1.0 shellingham-1.5.4 six-1.16.0 sortedcontainers-2.4.0 soundfile-0.12.1 speechbrain-1.0.0 sqlalchemy-2.0.31 submitit-1.5.1 sympy-1.13.1 tabulate-0.9.0 tensorboard-2.10.1 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1 tensorboardx-2.6 tensorflow-2.10.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.10.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.31.0 termcolor-2.4.0 threadpoolctl-3.5.0 tokenizers-0.15.2 tomli-2.0.1 tomlkit-0.13.0 torch-2.4.0 torch-audiomentations-0.11.1 torch-pitch-shift-1.2.4 torchaudio-2.4.0 torchmetrics-1.4.0.post0 tqdm-4.66.4 transformers-4.39.3 treetable-0.2.5 triton-3.0.0 typer-0.12.3 typing-extensions-4.12.2 typing-inspect-0.9.0 tzdata-2024.1 unidecode-1.3.8 urllib3-2.2.2 webcolors-24.6.0 websockets-12.0 werkzeug-3.0.3 wheel-0.43.0 whisperx-3.1.1 wrapt-1.16.0 yarl-1.9.4 yt-dlp-2024.7.25
#12 670.3 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager, possibly rendering your system unusable.It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv. Use the --root-user-action option if you know what you are doing and want to suppress this warning.
#12 DONE 673.9s

#13 exporting to image
#13 exporting layers
#13 exporting layers 66.8s done
#13 writing image sha256:0e5b5cdd5d7f2625177aff653c9a738c47e9cf174d5c419fe8b3498f1c7e33f9 done
#13 naming to docker.io/library/ultra-singer 0.0s done
#13 DONE 66.8s



I assume the file containing Levenshtein is within /opt/USinger/? If not where is it located and did you make your container aware of that location? [Edit] your question to include the output of pip show python-Levenshtein | grep Location You have a basic Python environment configuration error.

@Ramhound - I assume it lives with all the other python modules, but I'll edit the question once this build re-runs.

So you either need to move to /opt/USinger/ or change the python environment USinger is using to the same environment that contains /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages So what location does UltraSinger show?
